# Page not found error in django application

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am receiving that error when I try to visit the detail page of my post model. I have the slug field in the URL file, but it doesn't seem to matter.

Model

```
TYPE_STATUS = (
    ('post', 'Post'),
    ('page', 'Page'),
    ('media', 'Media'),
    ('menu', 'Menu'),
)    

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    type_status = models.CharField(max_length=70, default='post', 
    choices=TYPE_STATUS)
    description = models.TextField()
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

View

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.shortcuts import render
from posts.models import Post

class home_page(DetailView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(slug='home', featured=True)
    template_name = "home_page.html"
```

Urls

```
from .views import home_page

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', home_page.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

Comment: add error traceback

Comment: check it here http://prntscr.com/lylfrq

Comment: what  url you try to go details view? because your tried url doesn't match any of urlpatterns

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/home because i have called my post model on the home page

Comment: try this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/ `

Comment: yes i also tried out

Answer (score 0):

Change your URL like this

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', home_page.as_view(), name='home'),
```

Then be sure that you have a value in queryset in your CBV `DetailView`